# Is there any way to work with one setTimeout instead of many?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have this quite complicated custom animation, which uses a lot of `setTimeout()`

```
    var i=20;
     while(i!==0){
     setTimeout(function() {
     $("#feedback-toad").css("height","+=12");
     $("#feedback-toad").css("background-position", "50% "+i*(-5)+"%");
     }, i*100);
     i=i-1; }


    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#feedback-toad").prepend("<div id='toad-speaks'>SIGN UP OR LEAVE ME FEEDBACK, IF YOU DON'T WANT TO DO IT...</div>");
  , 2000);


   setTimeout(function() {
  $("#toad-speaks").html("SIGN UP OR LEAVE ME FEEDBACK, IF YOU DON'T WANT TO DO IT..  <br/> <br/> BUT YOU WANT TO ...");
    }, 4000);


    setTimeout(function() {
    $("#feedback-toad").animate({
    height:"60"}, 1000, function(){
     $("#feedback-toad").remove();
                       });
                       }, 6000);
```

I've read that using a lot of timeouts can really overload CPU, so possible issues with weak systems or smartphones.

Is there any way to optimaze this code, and use one or two timeouts? In the article it is said this is possible, but no clue how.

Comment: This is just wrong...

Comment: twenty-four timeouts is not "a lot of timeouts"

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't even see the while function. Next time, please take the time for proper indenting. Whenever there is an open bracket, the next line should be moved four spaces in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a pattern like this instead of your `while`

```
(function () { // give closure
    var i = 20;
    var doSomething = function () {
        if (i--) {
            $("#feedback-toad").css("height", "+=12");
            $("#feedback-toad").css("background-position", "50% " + i * (-5) + "%");
            setTimeout(doSomething, 100); // re-invoke
        }
    };
    setTimeout(doSomething, 100); // Start it off
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am surprised, if this works as you expect it to as you are missing closing brackets } in lines 12 and 23 or 24.

Besides that, you could possibly combine your 2000, 4000, 6000 timers to

- a 2000 timer, which contains:

  - a 2000 timer (former 4000), which contains:

    - a 2000 timer (former 6000)

However this will probably bring you absolutely no performance boost whatsoever.

And three is really not a lot. A lot would be tens, hundreds or even thousands (generated by automatic scripts). That could result into problems, starting with weaker systems. But with 3 or 4, you are definitely fine.

Comment: about syntax... this is probably happened while I was redactin code on SOF... it works fine.